# Get from list of dicts a certain quantity of items where a key meets some value

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's suppose I have the following list of dicts:

```
my_list = [
           {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 0}, 
           {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': -10}, 
           {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 
           {'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 
           {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 0}
]
```

I need to retrieve from this list two dicts where the key `a = 1`

How I can reach the desired result?

Comment: `filter(lambda d: d.get('a') == 1, my_list)`

Comment: +Reut Sharabani I need only two dicts! Your solution gives me all dicts where the values for key a = 1

Comment: Wrap the result with `islice(result, 0, 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to avoid iterating through the whole input list after you've already found the two dicts you need

```
from itertools import islice

a, b = islice((d for d in my_list if d.get('a') == 1), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a clear solution:

```
def a_is_1(d):
    return d.get('a') == 1

dicts = filter(a_is_1, my_list)
```

*Assuming* there are two dicts you can unpack them:

```
a, b, *rest = dicts
```

Otherwise just take as many as there are:

```
result = islice(dicts, 0, 2)
```

Each step does one thing and is very readable.

If you want this step for more keys and values you can use a closure:

```
def kv_filter(k, v):
    def _(d):
        return d.get(k) == v
    return _
```

And then:

```
dicts = filter(kv_filter('a', 1), my_list)
```

And the rest is the same.

Comment: I can achieve the desired result but +Patrick Haugh solution is more legible. Thanks!